# Word ordering of "worked on ... at ..."

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which of these two versions is correct? Note the word ordering of "worked on ... at ...".

A)

> In June 2022 I worked **at** company XY **on** the development of product YZ.

B)

> In June 2022 I worked **on** the development of product YZ **at** company
> XY.

Comment: At THE company. It depends on what you want to emphasise.

Comment: Both orders are fine.

Comment: So, @fev and dubious you would both say both is fine (depending on the emphasis)?

Comment: Normal word order is 2. First object and then adverbial of place. If you reverse the order, the emphasis falls on "at the company".

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to emphazise the company 1. is good? And it is gramatically correct?

Comment: "I worked on X at Y" sounds like a more neutral order. "I worked on the project at the office today." "Tomorrow, I will work at the office on a different project." Both are fine, but saying "at the office" first sounds like I am emphasizing that fact slightly.

Comment: People wouldn't tell you that sentences were 'fine' if they were not grammatically correct!

Comment: The general word order for adverbial phrases is Place Manner Time *In June 2022 I worked* [at company XY (Place)] [on the development of product YZ (Manner).] Changing this order tends to emphasise the new first adverbial.

Comment: Another factor is that if you have a very short phrase and a very long phrase, it's common to put the short one first regardless of other rules - this makes it easier to understand. E.g. "I worked at Apple on the development of a new form of analysis for calculating the..." vs "I worked on web services at a new technology startup in South Africa which was implementing a new system for..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general word order for adverbial phrases is Place, Manner, Time. So the default is

"I worked [at company XY (Place)] [on the development of product YZ (Manner)] [in June 2022 (Time)]"

Changing this order to [*In June 2022 (Time)*] I worked [at company XY (Place)] [on the development of product YZ (Manner).] tends to emphasise the new first adverbial, which is "time", i.e. when you worked there.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are perfectly grammatical.

1. In June 2022 I worked at company XY on the development of product
   YZ.
2. In June 2022 I worked on the development of product YZ at company XY.

The sentences consist of 1 verb phrase and 3 prepositional phrases.

We can form at least 24 grammatical sentences using these four phrases.

This shows how flexible the English language is.